# Print FixedDocument programmatically

Tags: wpf, printing

I am using a WPF FixedDocument with databinding for a simple invoice report. Works perfect when viewed inside the sofware itsself.

But i want to print a series of invoices in one click. The following code works perfect (quick 'n dirty, just loads an invoice one by one directly inside the viewmodel, for testing purposes) when I choose the XPS writer, bu fails to print correctly when printing to a real printer. I can see nothing of the data bound to the report. All the graphical elements such as lines are there, but no data. (When i print, with the same button, to de xps writer printer, all data is present, and correct...)

Any Ideas?

```
    private void ExecutePrintCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        var invs = args.Parameter as IList<object>;
        using (CompuDataContext db = new CompuDataContext())
        {
            DataLoadOptions dl = new DataLoadOptions();
            dl.LoadWith<Invoice>(f => f.Invoicelines);
            db.LoadOptions = dl;

            ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
            PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                PrintQueue q = dlg.PrintQueue;
                foreach (var o in invs)
                {

                    InvoiceListDisplay inv = o as InvoiceListDisplay;
                    Invoice invoice = db.Invoices.Single(f => f.Id == inv.Id);

                    viewer.DataContext = new InvoicePrintViewModel(invoice);

                    XpsDocumentWriter xpsdw = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(q);
                    xpsdw.Write(viewer.Document);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

mmkay, so I found the answer myself here :)

[This helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449036/why-am-i-losing-my-databinding-when-printing-to-an-xpsdocument) (Anybody an idea what the 'reason' behind is? Bug?)

PS: In a flowdocument, i experience the same issue, and have not been able to resolve it there. Any ideas?