# How to get this ListBox to be shown in XPS view?

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to get the XPS view of a ListBox following what is mentioned in this [answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/505717/466694)

```
FixedDocument fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();
PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();

ListBox lbx = new ListBox();
lbx.DataContext = lb.DataContext;

fixedPage.Children.Add(lbx);
pageContent.Child = fixedPage;
fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent);
//Create any other required pages here

docv.Document = fixedDoc;
```

lb is the ListBox shown in the top half of the image while the XPS view is below. However, it is empty except for the small square at the beginning. What am I doing wrong and how do I get the listbox to be shown in the XPS view.

[image: The Result looks like this]

Comment: does it help lbx.InvalidateMeasure() ?

Comment: @Klaus78: No, it doesn't. I tried it before.

Comment: perhaps this link may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449036/why-am-i-losing-my-databinding-when-printing-to-an-xpsdocument